# Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$, which of the following is uncountably infinite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$. Which of the following is uncountably infinite?

A) $A_1$

B) $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$

C) $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$

D) The set of all functions $f: \{0,1\} \to A_1$

E) The set of all functions $f: A_1 \to \{0, 1\}$

I am stupefied by this question, as none of the answers seem correct.  If $A_1$ is infinite, the answer would be $E$, but the question does not provide this further assumption.

Comment: i think what you say in the last is right

Answer (score 1):

"If $A_1$ is infinite, the answer would be E, but the question does not provide this further assumption."

I'd just go with that as the answer.

Comment: This was on the GRE which I took a few hours ago.